# Gnome Screensaver lock screen command not working...What can I do to fix this? ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gnome-screensaver

The gnome screensaver in ubuntu 14.04 64 bits doesnt work anymore and when I try to lock screen either by the gui through the right hand corner or through the command line in terminal. The screen just flashes and it doesn't lock. I have tried installing and reinstalling gnome-screensaver in synaptics and still the screen doesn't lock. Any ideas ?

thanks,

Kind Regards

eins

Answer (score 2):

It seems that somehow my user got added to the nopasswordlogin group. Removing my user from this group would solve the problem so I solved this by going into the terminal and typing in the command line:  sudo gedit /etc/group and deleting my user name from the nopasswdlogin group in the text file and then saving the file again. Now I can lock the screen and the system requests a password on the ubuntu login screen. The screen wouldn't lock before because there was no password with which to lock the screen. The system didn't request a password because the user was in the nopasswordlogin group. Thanks.

Kind Regards